# Blue Prism - Control Room issue

Tags: session, soap, blueprism

I am using Blue Prism in a local installation and I would like to schedule a task.
I am not able to do so, since the Session Info of my Runtime Resource (the only one I have, since it is a local installation) has 2 pending processes on it, but I have not any in the Environment part of the Control Room.
For more detail, check the attached picture.

When I type in the browser http://localhost:8181/busy the answer is **yes**.
When I type in the browser http://localhost:8181/connections I see this result:

- OUTBOUND: disabled
- INBOUND: 2
- 127.0.0.1 (MyPc)
- 127.0.0.1 ()

What can I do to kill the 2 pending sessions?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: You mentioned you're using a local installation of Blue Prism - do you happen to be connected to an instance of Blue Prism Server?

Answer (score 2):

Can you triple check that there are no pending sessions waiting to be started? I've seen that error happen when there is old pending session that had not been resolved.

Would you be so kind, to open control room, remove all filters (especially the date!) and set one filter for status "pending".

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, Only solution (Yet) is rebooting the resource PC. Then you will see "No sessions" in Session Info and you can run process.

This usually happens when you delete the pending item while resource is not connected.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to check again in Control room by marking 'ALL' in the filters and select 'Pending' as the status.

I am almost certain that there must be something pending. This happens with me many times and every time I had to reset the filters.

Let me know if this will help.